# Eloquent using wrong table name

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have a model called `ReferrerMedium` along with a migration for a `referrer_mediums` table.

Here is my class:

```
namespace App;

class ReferrerMedium extends \Eloquent
{
    //
}
```

Here is my migration:

```
Schema::create('referrer_mediums', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('name');
});
```

Here is my code:

```
foreach (ReferrerMedium::all() as $referrer_medium) {
    $options[$referrer_medium->name] = $referrer_medium->name;
}
```

This code is causing the error `Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'leadbind.referrer_media' doesn't exist`

Why is it attempting to query the `referrer_media` table instead of `referrer_mediums`???

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `medium`'s plural type is `media`, therefore you should manually specified table name in you model:

```
protected $table = 'referrer_mediums';
```

But i recommend that you should make a migration to change the table name.

Comment: Your advanced knowledge of inflection is outstanding! Lol, thanks!

Comment: It's my pleasure.

Comment: Why did you add the `$` back in front of `protected`?

Comment: Oh, i fixed it. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

It's general definition standard that if you create a table with plural name and create model for this table as singular, then model automatically connects corresponding table, otherwise you should define table name in model like:

```
$protected $table = 'referrer_mediums';
```

In your case, Model name is `ReferrerMedium` so it will search for the singular of `ReferrerMedium` which is `referrer_media` that's the reason behind your problem.

So, either you can create table as `referrer_media` or define table name in model as above.

Hope you understand.